# Shortcut keys to arrange SQL inline query to multi line query

Tags: sql, inline, shortcut

Is there any shortcut key to arrange SQL query from inline to multi-line query for easy reading.

Example :

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID = 23 and EMP_NAME = 'JOHN'

Short cut key would concert above query to

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMP_ID = 23 
AND EMP_NAME = 'JOHN'
```

I remember while using SQL server 2005, there was a short cut key i used. forgot now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) !!!

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for this. Currently I'm using **[Red Gate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)**. But there are many alternatives for this such as

**[Instant SQL Formatter (online formatting tool)](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)** 
**[Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter (free plugin)](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx)** 
**[SQL Formatter (online)](http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html)** 
**[T-SQL Tidy (online)](http://www.tsqltidy.com/)** 
**[Poor SQL (online)](http://poorsql.com/)** 
**[SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is another SQL Formatter with many formatting options at www.sqlinform.com . it also has a Windows Hotkey feature. So, you can format the SQL in your SQL managment Tool with one click. The online version is free.